# YQ edit files with multiple document in place

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a YAML file with 2 documents

```
# template.yaml

a : 1
---
b : 2
```

I'm trying to edit the YAML file inplace. I've tried using

```
# yq4

yq -i '
    select(documentIndex == 0) | 
    .a = 3 |
    select(documentIndex == 1) |
    .b = 4
' template.yaml
```

But figured out that this outputs an empty file. I figured that the output of `select(documentIndex == 0) | .a = 3` is a single document, which when piped to `select(documentIndex == 1)`, results in an empty document.

In yq3, I can do this by writing

```
#yq3

yq w -d1 .a 3 | yq w -d2 .b 4` > template.yaml
```

Is there an equivalent to this yq4 command in yq3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it right, on why it doesn't work with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) v4. A simpler way to do that would be to do

```bash
yq 'select(di == 0).a  = 3  | select(di == 1).b = 5'  yaml
```

It is not recommended to use the in-place substitution flag, before verifying the contents of the stdout. Always add it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think this should be added into the example

Answer (score 2):

I figured out another way to do a more roundabout way to do it.

We can split and then merge the files together

```
yq 'select(documentIndex == 0)  | .a = 3' > doc_0.yaml
yq 'select(documentIndex == 1)  | .b = 4' > doc_0.yaml

yq eval-all '. as $item' doc_0.yaml doc_1.yaml > $output.yaml
```

It turns out that the differnt files are read and written out as documents.